# How can you get the Linux thread Id of a std::thread()

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I was playing with `std::thread` and I was wondering how is it possible to get the thread id of a new `std::thread()`,  I am not talking about `std::thread::id` but rather  the OS Id given to the thread ( you can view it using `pstree`).
This is only for my knowledge, and it's targeted only to Linux platforms (no need to be portable).

I can get the Linux Thread Id within the thread like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void SayHello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello ! my id is " << (long int)syscall(SYS_gettid) << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::thread t1(&SayHello);
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

But how can I retrieve the same id within the main loop ? I did not find a way using  `std::thread::native_handle`. I believed it was possible to get it trough `pid_t gettid(void);` since the c++11 implementation relies on pthreads, but i must be wrong.

Any advices ?
Thank you.

Comment: What is wrong with `std::thread::native_handle()`?

Comment: @AndyProwl - `native_handle()` and `native_handle_type` are not required to exist, and if they do exist, what you can do with the resulting object is implementation-defined. There are **no** portable semantics. Maybe a particular implementation supports doing this, but that's a matter between the user and the library documentation.

Comment: @AndyProwl it returns me the same value as `std::thread::id`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: I understand that, but I was assuming the OP is OK with doing something non-portable (as he is specifically targeting one platform), and I expected the implementation to provide such a basic information. I understand it is not required to provide it, but I would find it weird if it didn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you're using GCC standard library, `std::thread::native_handle()` returns the `pthread_t` thread ID returned by `pthread_self()`, not the OS thread ID returned by `gettid()`. `std::thread::id()` is a wrapper around that same `pthread_t`, and GCC's `std::thread` doesn't provide any way to get the OS thread ID, but you could create your own mapping:

```
std::mutex m;
std::map<std::thread::id, pid_t> threads;
void add_tid_mapping()
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
  threads[std::this_thread::get_id()] = syscall(SYS_gettid);
}
void wrap(void (*f)())
{
  add_tid_mapping();
  f();
}
```

Then create your thread with:

```
std::thread t1(&wrap, &SayHello);
```

then get the ID with something like:

```
pid_t tid = 0;
while (tid == 0)
{
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(m);
  if (threads.count(t1.get_id()))
    tid = threads[t1.get_id()];
}
```

Comment: Oh getting the id this way is smart, that's great , thanks you !

Comment: Why would you build a std::map? Is the `syscall()` expected to be so expensive? Also, you never seem to remove threads from the map, which could be viewed as a memory leak (e.g. in a webserver setting where many threads are spawned over time and the process typically runs for months without restarting).

Comment: @theswine, the syscall gives you the ID of the current thread, the map lets you find the ID of _any_ thread, given its `thread::id`. That's more flexible. It's not strictly a leak, since the memory is still reachable, but to keep the memory usage bounded (and to cope with thread IDs being reused) you could use a `thread_local` object that adds to the map in its constructor and removes from the map in its destructor. The answer was a sketch demonstrating a solution, if you want something more robust then make it more robust.

Comment: @JonathanWakely You are right, I did not realize that you might want to get thread id *outside* of the thread. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize that the `while(tid ==0)` is very important because the parent thread might reach the get thread id statement earlier than the mapping happens.

Answer (score 1):

Some pthread [implementations](https://www.minocacorp.com/doc/1375/element/360862/), e.g. [Android 21](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/0fd7f83fce248c4972d5659de975300d8366fbb9/ndk/platforms/android-L/include/pthread.h#191)+, provide

```
pid_t pthread_gettid_np(pthread_t);
```

The implementation may use the internal structure of `struct pthread_t` to retrieve the native thread id, same as the one returned by `gettid()` or `syscall(SYS_gettid)` when called in the context of that thread.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
pid_t gettid (void)
{
    return syscall(__NR_gettid);
}
```

http://yusufonlinux.blogspot.com/2010/11/get-thread-id-from-linux.html

Looks like __NR_gettid is defined in unistd.h

Comment: I think this is useful if you have a wrapper around `std:thread` or `pthreads`, but I can't call it from outside the thread. (correct me if I'm wrong). Thanks.