# How to extract taskid(tid) of a pthread from the parent thread?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

I'm using std::thread to launch threads. Also, I need stats for the worker thread available at `/proc/[pid]/tasks/[tid]`. I need tid to be able to monitor thread stats. I was wondering if there was a way to extract `tid` from the parent thread. I know that syscall gettid() from the worker returns its id, but I want the threadId from the master and not the slave. Is there a way to extract `tid` from the thread_id gor from std::thread.get_tid() ?

I believe there might be better ways of doing this, please suggest :)

UPDATE:
[How can you get the Linux thread Id of a std::thread()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708983/how-can-you-get-the-linux-thread-id-of-a-stdthread) this provides some information on getting tid from the worker, adds an overhead to the thread launch. For instance, `std::thread t = std::thread(&wrapper);`  `t.get_id()` can be called from the launcher thread. I was/am looking if there was a to do the same thing from the main/launcher thread in a safe way.

Comment: There is no relationship for threads unlike processes like successor-predecessor.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can you get the Linux thread Id of a std::thread()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708983/how-can-you-get-the-linux-thread-id-of-a-stdthread)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you get the Linux thread Id of a std::thread()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708983/how-can-you-get-the-linux-thread-id-of-a-stdthread)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All threads have a unique id:
`std::thread::id  this_id  =  std::this_thread::get_id();`

You can store it in a variable when the program starts and it'll be accessible from the other threads.

I understand what you mean when you say *parent* thread, but even though one thread gave birth to another, they are siblings.

if you want the *master* thread to be able to get the `/proc` path to each *worker* thread, you could wrap the worker thread object in a class that, when it starts the actual thread, creates a path property that the master can later get.

An example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

// A base class for thread object wrappers
class abstract_thread {
public:
    abstract_thread() {}

    abstract_thread(const abstract_thread&) = delete;
    abstract_thread(abstract_thread&& rhs) :
        m_th(std::move(rhs.m_th)), m_terminated(rhs.m_terminated), m_cv{}, m_mtx{} {}
    abstract_thread& operator=(const abstract_thread&) = delete;
    abstract_thread& operator=(abstract_thread&& rhs) {
        terminate();
        join();
        m_th = std::move(rhs.m_th);
        m_terminated = rhs.m_terminated;
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~abstract_thread() {
        // make sure we don't destroy a running thread object
        terminate();
        join();
    }

    virtual void start() {
        if(joinable())
            throw std::runtime_error("thread already running");
        else {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
            m_terminated = true;
            // start thread and wait for it to signal that setup has been done
            m_th = std::thread(&abstract_thread::proxy, this);
            m_cv.wait(lock, [this] { return m_terminated == false; });
        }
    }
    inline bool joinable() const { return m_th.joinable(); }
    inline void join() {
        if(joinable()) {
            m_th.join();
        }
    }
    inline void terminate() { m_terminated = true; }
    inline bool terminated() const { return m_terminated; }

protected:
    // override if thread specific setup needs to be done before start() returns
    virtual void setup_in_thread() {}
    // must be overridden in derived classes
    virtual void execute() = 0;

private:
    std::thread m_th{};
    bool m_terminated{};
    std::condition_variable m_cv{};
    std::mutex m_mtx{};

    void proxy() {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mtx);
            setup_in_thread(); // call setup function
            m_terminated = false;
            m_cv.notify_one();
        }
        execute(); // run thread code
    }
};

// an abstract thread wrapper capable of returning its /proc path
class proc_path_thread : public abstract_thread {
public:
    // function to call from master to get the path
    const std::string& get_proc_path() const { return m_proc_path; }

protected:
    void setup_in_thread() override {
        m_proc_path =
            std::move(std::string("/proc/")) + std::to_string(syscall(SYS_gettid));
    }

private:
    std::string m_proc_path{};
};

// two different thread wrapper classes. Just inherit proc_path_thread and implement
// "execute()". Loop until terminated() is true (or you're done with the work)
class AutoStartThread : public proc_path_thread {
public:
    AutoStartThread() { start(); }

private:
    void execute() override {
        while(!terminated()) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
            std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " AutoStartThread running\n";
        }
    }
};

class ManualStartThread : public proc_path_thread {
    void execute() override {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
        std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << " ManualStartThread running\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    }
};

int main() {
    AutoStartThread a;
    std::cout << a.get_proc_path() << "\t// AutoStartThread, will have path\n";

    ManualStartThread b;
    std::cout << b.get_proc_path()
              << "\t// ManualStartThread not started, no path\n";
    b.start();
    std::cout << b.get_proc_path()
              << "\t// ManualStartThread will now have a path\n";
    b.join();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1500));
    // terminate() + join() is called automatically when abstract_thread descendants
    // goes out of scope:
    //
    // a.terminate();
    // a.join();
}
```

Possible output:

```
/proc/38207 // AutoStartThread, will have path
    // ManualStartThread not started, no path
/proc/38208 // ManualStartThread will now have a path
139642064209664 ManualStartThread running
139642072602368 AutoStartThread running
139642072602368 AutoStartThread running
139642072602368 AutoStartThread running
139642072602368 AutoStartThread running
```

Comment: This is actually the other way round of what I wanted, I don't like using gettid() from the worker(I feel it bloats perf, as one would need to gaurd or keep checking a global variable for tid to be populated). For instance with 

`std::thread t = std::thread(&wrapper);` ; `t.get_id()` from the context of the main would give the actual thread id.

what do you think?

Comment: Ok, I see. Sure, you could do it the other way around so that the master queries for the worker's paths. Just add a `condition_variable` for each thread that signals master that the native `pid_t` has been put in the `map`. Perhaps best make a class around the thread object with some synchronization so you can do `th.get_path()` in a safe way.

Comment: @ShashankHegde Made a new version. Hope I got you right this time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the thread through a function whose first task will be to message it's id, e.g., either classically using mutexes and condvars:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct tid_msg{
    pthread_mutex_t mx;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    pid_t tid;
};
void *thr(void*A)
{
    struct tid_msg *msg = A;
    pid_t tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&msg->mx);
    msg->tid = tid;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&msg->mx);
    pthread_cond_signal(&msg->cond);
    printf("my tid=%lu\n", (long unsigned)tid);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    struct tid_msg msg = { PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, -1 };
    pthread_t ptid;
    pthread_create(&ptid,0,thr,&msg);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&msg.mx);
    while(-1==msg.tid) pthread_cond_wait(&msg.cond,&msg.mx);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&msg.mx);

    printf("their tid=%lu\n", (long unsigned)msg.tid);
    pthread_join(ptid,0);
}
```

or simply via an atomic variable (relaxed memory ordering should be fine here,
but you can play it safe and use the sequentially consistent default):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>

void *thr(void*A)
{
    _Atomic pid_t *tidp = A;
    pid_t tid;
    tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    atomic_store_explicit(tidp, tid, memory_order_relaxed);
    printf("my tid=%lu\n", (long unsigned)tid);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    _Atomic pid_t tid=-1;
    pthread_t ptid;
    pthread_create(&ptid,0,thr,&tid);

    while(-1==atomic_load_explicit(&tid,memory_order_relaxed)) ;

    printf("their tid=%lu\n", (long unsigned)tid);
    pthread_join(ptid,0);
}
```

Comment: Both options are essentially waiting on CV to spin. I'm wondering which option is better for performance? esp. when there are a lot of threads to manage? Thanks so much :)

Comment: @ShashankHegde I'd bet on the spinning version (atomics). Thread creation shouldn't so long as to warrant putting the parent thread to sleep.